# GitHub actions/checkout wipes filesystem on runner

Tags: github-actions

I have the following workflow section:

```
jobs:
  terraform:
    name: 'Terraform'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    # Checkout the module repository to the GitHub Actions runner
    - name: Checkout Modules
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
      with:
        repository: myaccount/myrepo

    - name: Show Filesystem1
      run: ls -l -R
      
    - name: Checkout Client
      uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Show Filesystem2
      run: ls -l -R
```

When I inspect the filesystem on the runner at steps 1 and 2, I get the following:

```
.:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 6 runner docker 4096 Apr  7 12:55 modules

./modules:
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 3 runner docker 4096 Apr  7 12:55 client_network
drwxr-xr-x 2 runner docker 4096 Apr  7 12:55 databases
drwxr-xr-x 2 runner docker 4096 Apr  7 12:55 storage
drwxr-xr-x 2 runner docker 4096 Apr  7 12:55 virtualmachines

./modules/client_network:
total 40
drwxr-xr-x 2 runner docker  4096 Apr  7 12:55 gateway
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker  4538 Apr  7 12:55 main.tf
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker   203 Apr  7 12:55 outputs.tf
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker 23347 Apr  7 12:55 variables.tf
```

and for step 2:

```
.:
total 24
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker 1291 Apr  7 12:52 keyvault.tf
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker 3538 Apr  7 12:52 main-1.tf
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker  638 Apr  7 12:52 outputs.tf
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker  387 Apr  7 12:52 provider.tf
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker   56 Apr  7 12:52 terraform.tfvars
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker 2020 Apr  7 12:52 variables.tf
```

The result is in essence that the modules folder is wiped and terraform apply will fail because the module folder referenced in main-1.tf is gone.
I have no idea how to accomplish having both repositories side by side.

Thanks!

Comment: Both repos are there but in your case the second checkout should create a nested directory inside the first one. You can verify this by running `pwd` and `ls -l -R ../`. However, checking out using [`path`](https://github.com/actions/checkout#usage) should resolve your issue as mentioned in the answer below.

Comment: That's right, I verified it this way too. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe use [Checkout multiple repos (side by side)](https://github.com/actions/checkout#checkout-multiple-repos-side-by-side)

```
- name: Checkout Modules
  uses: actions/checkout@v3
  with:
    repository: myaccount/myrepo
    path: modules

- name: Checkout Client
  uses: actions/checkout@v3
  with:
    path: client
```

Comment: Thanks, I did need to also change the structure in the modules repo to accomplish this but the basic issue was that I needed to specify a path as well.